# How to round the mesh that has a little complicated form?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edit-mode

I tried to apply the bevel modifier to get a semicircle from the top of the rectangle but It worked only for a simple shape where the vertices between opposite corners weren't interrupted by other vertices. I can't join the 1, 2, 3 and 4 faces together either because the mesh is a little curved from the view from the top. So could you give me some advice?

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Try to select one vertice and hit G twice. Now you can drag that vertice along the edge direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *Proportional editing* for this.

Use you regular *Move tool* to move the vertices, and check *Proportional editing*.
Play with the falloff profile and size.

You might also need to check *Projected (2D)* in your case.

[image]

Comment: I tried this advice. I also added extra edges and applied Bevel to round corners. it turned out pretty good

Comment: @GrigoryMovchan Glad to hear it helped you :). You can now mark the answer as accepted for others with a similar problem.